# How can I find the right xpath and loop over table?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I would like to get all the values from the table "Elektriciteit NL" on https://powerhouse.net/forecast-prijzen-onbalans/. However after endlessly trying to find the right xpath using selenium I was not able to scrape the table.

I tried to use "inspect" and copy the xpath from the table to identify the length of the table for scraping later. After this failed I tried to use "contain" however this was not succesfull either. Afterwards i tried some things using BeautifullSoup however without any luck.

```
#%%
import pandas as pd

from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
#%% powerhouse Elektriciteit NL base & peak

url = "https://powerhouse.net/forecast-prijzen-onbalans/"

#%% open webpagina
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path + 'chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

#%%
prices = []


#loop for values in table
for j in range(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@id="endex_nl_forecast"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]'))):
    base = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@id="endex_nl_forecast"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]')[j]


#%%
#trying with BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 


response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

table  = soup.find('table', id = 'endex_nl_forecast')
rows = soup.find_all('tr')
```

I would like to have the table in a dataframe and understand how xpath exactly works. I'm kind of new to the whole concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to ways other than xpath you could do this without selenium or xpath:

you could just use pandas

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_html('https://powerhouse.net/forecast-prijzen-onbalans/')[4]
```

If you want text representation of icons you could extract the class name of the `svg` which describes arrow direction from the appropriate `td`s.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://powerhouse.net/forecast-prijzen-onbalans/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.select_one('#endex_nl_forecast table')
rows = []
headers = [i.text for i in table.select('th')]

for tr in table.select('tr')[1:]:
    rows.append([i.text if i.svg is None else i.svg['class'][2].split('-')[-1] for i in tr.select('td') ])

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = headers)
print(df)
```

---

**Sample rows:**

[image]

Comment: second solution is nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium driver to locate the table & its contents,

```
url = 'https://powerhouse.net/forecast-prijzen-onbalans/'
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)
```

To Read Table Headers & Print

```
tableHeader = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='endex_nl_forecast']//thead//th")
print(tableHeader)
for header in tableHeader:
    print(header.text)
```

To Find number of rows in the table

```
rowElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='endex_nl_forecast']//tbody/tr")
print('Total rows in the table:', len(rowElements))
```

To print each rows as is

```
for row in rowElements:
    print(row.text)
```